# How to remove last digit from string

Tags: oracle, plsql

i want to remove the last digit of string one by one by using collection but when i remove last digit, it also removes zero from starting

```
declare
type t_list is table of mk_suk.CALLED_NBR%type;
v_array t_list;
idx number;
ids number;

begin

select substr(CALLED_NBR,1,(LENGTH(CALLED_NBR))) bulk collect into v_array from mk_suk;

for i in v_array.first..v_array.last loop
dbms_output.put_line(v_array(i));
ids:=v_array(i);

loop
select substr(ids,1,(LENGTH(ids)-1))  into idx from mk_suk where CALLED_NBR=v_array(i);

ids:=idx;

dbms_output.put_line(idx);

exit when length(idx)\<2;

end loop;
end loop;

end;

/
```

query result

```
09589583145
958958314
95895831
9589583
958958
95895
9589
958
95
9
```

Comment: Because number is a number, it has no format. Oracle doesn't prepend any zeroes to number because at least it cannot know how much of them you want to see.

Answer (score 2):

oracle doesn't "remove zeroes from start", it converts it to a number.Number 0001 is the same as 1 and the variable `ids` and `idx` are both number.

```
koen 19c>SELECT LENGTH(0001) as anumber, LENGTH('0001') as astring from dual;

   ANUMBER    ASTRING 
__________ __________ 
         1          4 

koen 19c>
```

so in a loop there is a difference:

```
koen 19c>declare
  2    l_string VARCHAR2(100) := '0123';
  3    l_nr NUMBER := 0123;
  4  begin
  5    FOR i IN 1 .. LENGTH(l_string) LOOP
  6      dbms_output.put_line('string:' || l_string);
  7      l_string := SUBSTR(l_string,1,LENGTH(l_string)-1);
  8    END LOOP;
  9    FOR i IN 1 .. LENGTH(l_nr) LOOP
 10      dbms_output.put_line('l_nr:' || l_nr);
 11      l_nr := SUBSTR(l_nr,1,LENGTH(l_nr)-1);
 12    END LOOP;
 13  END;
 14* /
string:0123
string:012
string:01
string:0
l_nr:123
l_nr:12
l_nr:1


PL/SQL procedure successfully completed.
```

Answer (score 1):

Your code is wrong because - in declaration section - you declared both variables as `NUMBER`. If they were *strings* (and code modified - why fetching from the table again, if you have that value in a collection already?), it *works*:

Sample data:

```
SQL> desc mk_suk
 Name                                      Null?    Type
 ----------------------------------------- -------- ----------------------------
 CALLED_NBR                                         VARCHAR2(20)

SQL> select * from mk_suk;

CALLED_NBR
--------------------
09589583145

SQL> set serveroutput on
```

Your code, modified:

```
SQL> DECLARE
  2     TYPE t_list IS TABLE OF mk_suk.CALLED_NBR%TYPE;
  3     v_array  t_list;
  4     idx      mk_suk.CALLED_NBR%TYPE;  --   NUMBER;
  5     ids      mk_suk.CALLED_NBR%TYPE;  --   NUMBER;
  6  BEGIN
  7     SELECT SUBSTR (CALLED_NBR, 1, (LENGTH (CALLED_NBR)))
  8       BULK COLLECT INTO v_array
  9       FROM mk_suk;
 10
 11     FOR i IN v_array.FIRST .. v_array.LAST
 12     LOOP
 13        DBMS_OUTPUT.put_line (v_array (i));
 14
 15        ids := v_array (i);
 16
 17        LOOP
 18           idx := SUBSTR (ids, 1, (LENGTH (ids) - 1));
 19           ids := idx;
 20           DBMS_OUTPUT.put_line (idx);
 21
 22           EXIT WHEN LENGTH (idx) < 2;
 23        END LOOP;
 24     END LOOP;
 25  END;
 26  /
```

Result:

```
09589583145
0958958314
095895831
09589583
0958958
095895
09589
0958
095
09
0

PL/SQL procedure successfully completed.

SQL>
```

Answer (score 0):

You are using a `NUMBER` data type for the `ids` and `idx` variables. `NUMBER` is a binary data-type that uses 1 byte per 2 digits and does not store leading zeroes or trailing decimal zeroes (since `0123`, `123` and `123.000` all have the same numeric value) and is **NEVER** stored in any particular human-readable format (as it uses a binary format).

If you want to keep the leading zeroes then do not use `NUMBER` and use `VARCHAR2` or continue using the column data type `MK_SUK.CALLED_NBR%TYPE`.

However, you do not need all the temporary variables and can simplify the code to:

```sql
DECLARE
  TYPE t_list IS TABLE OF mk_suk.CALLED_NBR%TYPE;
  v_array t_list;
BEGIN
  SELECT called_nbr
  BULK COLLECT INTO v_array
  FROM   mk_suk;

  FOR i IN 1 .. v_array.COUNT LOOP
    FOR l IN REVERSE 1 .. LENGTH(v_array(i)) LOOP
      DBMS_OUTPUT.PUT_LINE(SUBSTR(v_array(i), 1, l));
    END LOOP;
  END LOOP;
END;
/
```

Then, if you have the sample data:

```sql
CREATE TABLE mk_suk (called_nbr) AS
SELECT '09589583145' FROM DUAL;
```

The output is:

> ```
> 09589583145
> 0958958314
> 095895831
> 09589583
> 0958958
> 095895
> 09589
> 0958
> 095
> 09
> 0
> ```

[fiddle](https://dbfiddle.uk/dD1qxONm)

Answer (score 0):

Did you consider the option to do it with just a simple SQL:

```sql
Select      SubStr(CALLED_NBR, 1, LEVEL) "NBRS"
From      ( Select '09589583145' "CALLED_NBR" From  Dual )
Connect By  LEVEL <= Length(CALLED_NBR)
Order BY    LEVEL Desc

--  NBRS       
--  -----------
--  09589583145
--  0958958314
--  095895831
--  09589583
--  0958958
--  095895
--  09589
--  0958
--  095
--  09
--  0
```

And if the goal is to work it out using collection then the same SQL could do the job in PL/SQL block like below:

```sql
SET SERVEROUTPUT ON
DECLARE
  TYPE t_list IS TABLE OF VARCHAR2(20);
  v_array t_list;
BEGIN
  Select      SubStr(CALLED_NBR, 1, LEVEL) "NBRS" BULK COLLECT INTO v_array
  From        ( Select '09589583145' "CALLED_NBR" From  Dual )
  Connect By  LEVEL <= Length(CALLED_NBR)
  Order BY    LEVEL Desc;
  --
  FOR i IN 1 .. v_array.Count LOOP
    DBMS_OUTPUT.PUT_LINE(v_array(i));
  END LOOP;
END;
/

--  09589583145
--  0958958314
--  095895831
--  09589583
--  0958958
--  095895
--  09589
--  0958
--  095
--  09
--  0
--  
--  PL/SQL procedure successfully completed.
```